# Form value always read as undefined in Javascript

Tags: javascript, forms, input, undefined

I'm a new self taught programmer working on my first homework assignment, so I apologize if my naming convention is off.  This is the most bizarre thing.  No matter how I request the input value, (hoping to pull a number) it always reads as undefined.

Everything works in my javascript function except pulling the input value. I have used forms in the past,  and the variables appear to be referencing it fine; I have tried both document.formName.inputName.value, as well as document.getElementById ('input-id').value and it returns undefined. I have renamed my form and variables so many times to see if that was the issue and stI'll nothing.  I have tried both input type text and number,  and stI'll undefined.

Am I missing something due to how new I am?  Please help. Links to github and jsfiddle below.

https://github.com/MissElle/calculator?files=1
https://jsfiddle.net/MissElle/qf7xL8gj/

```
var dataInput = document.compute.calculate.value;
var element = Number(dataInput);
var numCount = document.getElementById('count');
var numSum = document.getElementById('sum');
var numMean = document.getElementById('mean');

var subCount = [];
var subSum = 0; 
var starColors = ['#51fffc', '#ffff96', '#96ffc7', '#f8d8ff', '#d2bfff', '#ffbfbf', '#ffd299', '#ffffff', '#000000'];

function calcData(element) {
  if(typeof element === 'number') {
    console.log(element);
    subCount.push(element);
    var starDiv = document.createElement('div');
    starDiv.className = 'star';
    var starHolder = document.getElementById('star-holder');
    starHolder.appendChild(starDiv);
    starDiv.style.background = 'radial-gradient(circle, ' + starColors[Math.floor(Math.random() * starColors.length)] + ', transparent, transparent)';
    numCount.innerHTML = subCount.length;
    for(var i in subCount) {
      subSum += subCount[i];
      numSum.innerHTML = subSum;
      var subMean = subSum/subCount.length;
      numMean.innerHTML = subMean;
    }
  }else {
    numCount.innerHTML = 'Not a Number';
    console.log(element);
  }
  subSum = 0;
  event.preventDefault();
}


function clearData() {
  subCount = [];
  subSum = 0;
  subMean = 0;
  numSum.innerHTML = '';
  numMean.innerHTML = '';
  numCount.innerHTML = '';

  var starHolder = document.getElementById('star-holder');
  var starDiv = starHolder.getElementsByClassName('star');

  while(starDiv.length > 0) {
    starHolder.removeChild(starDiv[0]);
  }
}


<form name="compute" onsubmit="calcData()" onReset="clearData()">
         <p class="bold">Please enter a number</p>
         <input type="number" name="calculate" id="calculation" step="any"><br>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="star">
        <input type="reset" value="nostar" name="clearForm">
         <div class="row">
           <div class="typevalue"><h4>Count:</h4><h4>Sum:</h4><h4>Mean:</h4></div>
           <div class="numbervalue"><p id="count"></p><p id="sum"></p><p id="mean"></p></div>
        </div>
      </form>
```

Comment: because you read the dataInput when the script runs, not after the value is changed.

Answer (score 0):

Move your variable declarations inside your function like this:

```
function calcData(element) {
    var dataInput = document.compute.calculate.value;
    var element = Number(dataInput);
    var numCount = document.getElementById('count');
    var numSum = document.getElementById('sum');
    var numMean = document.getElementById('mean');
    var subCount = [];
    var subSum = 0; 
    var starColors = ['#51fffc', '#ffff96', '#96ffc7', '#f8d8ff', '#d2bfff', 
        '#ffbfbf', '#ffd299', '#ffffff', '#000000'];
...
```

If you declare your `dataInput` outside the function you get no value because that JS code is run after the page loads (before your user types any number in your function).
You have to declare it inside your function that way you get the value of your input when the user clicks on the button.